# WSO2 Decoupling Tomcat and ESB

Tags: rest, tomcat, wso2

i m working with WSO2 EBS 4.7.0.
I have some REST services i have to deploy on a tomcat server.
Is it possible to have this configuration?

WSO2 ESB CLUSTER ----> TOMCAT CLUSTER (separate server)---> REST WEBSERVICES

I mean, is it possibile to decouple the tomcat contained by the ESB and locate it on a separate server in clustered mode? How can this be done?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible. I mean decoupling tomcat from wso2esb. ESB runs on top of tomcat.

Why do you prefer this setup? 
You can host your services in WSO2AS.

ESB cluster-->AS clusters

Comment: Well, maybe i'd have to explain better what i mean. I don't want to take out the tomcat inside the esb. I mean instead to realize this configuration: [WSO2 ESB cluster] balancing the load on ----> [Tomcat Cluster] exposing [REST web services] . Is it possibile to configure the Wso2 ELB for balancing tomcat cluster nodes?